# Our Team not showing on website

Tags: wp-admin

I am having an issue with our website.  Under the "Our Company" section, "Our Team" is not being displayed.  Will someone mind assisting/helping please?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot, you're trying to use an `[our-team]` shortcode which does not exist. You may have deactivated a plugin or made changes to a theme which caused the shortcode to no longer exist. You should look through backups to see what changed and reactivate the plugin or theme that creates the `our-team` shortcode.